# Call OCaml functions that require unix.cma in C

Tags: c, ocaml

I have an OCaml library and some wrapper defined around it in C.
I followed the steps in http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/intfc.html (section 19.8) to compile a main.c program
so that I can test everything.

The problem is that, when initialising the OCaml engine by doing

```
caml_startup(argv);
```

it gets me a lot of erros. One of them is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_unix_truncate", referenced from:
  _caml_builtin_cprim in modcaml.o
```

How can I solve this?

Do I need a certain kind of special linking when using external libraries?

EDIT:

To compile I use

```
cc -o prog -I `ocamlc -where` main.c mod.a -ltermcap
```

Just as the instruction by INRIA.

The main code is written in OCaml.

Comment: Show the command used for linking your application (and how do you compile it); so **edit your question** to improve it. Is the main program coded in C or in Ocaml? Are you using the bytecode or the native compiler?

Comment: Edited. I am using the ocamlc compiler, just like in the page. Maybe that is the problem.

Comment: Where does mod.a come from? There are no obvious OCaml modules at all on your compile line. Second question: what kind of system are you working on? It would be best if you could make a complete, very tiny example that shows your problem. I have linked C & OCaml many times, it definitely does work. Even in fairly exotic settings (such as iOS).

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's simple enough to generate ocaml byte code as .o or C file by using ocamlbuild:

```
ocamlbuild program.byte.c
```

or

```
ocamlbuild program.byte.o
```

or by using instructions from nice RWO book:
https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/the-compiler-backend-byte-code-and-native-code.html

But for the next step, we want merge byte code with our C code we will have some stupid difficulties, in case our code depends from other ocaml packages.
As you prefer to use C compiler/linker there is simple tricks to know where were placed ocaml libraries you use into your code:

```
ocamlc -where
```

and you can use *nm* utility to find libraries where undefined symbols live:

```
find `ocamlc -where` -iname *.a |xargs nm -o |grep "T your_symbol"
```

If you remember which libraries you have used you can use more concrete pipeline:

```
find `ocamlfind query used_module` -iname *.a |xargs nm -o |grep "T your_symbol"
```

For now you know required libraries and their paths, so you can modify you command line for CC.